# Scope of a local variable within a class

Tags: java, oop

My understanding of a local variable is that it is declared within a function/method. Instance variables are ones which are declared inside a class and have a class-wide scope. So the statement that the scope of local variables is within a class should be false as local variables are valid only in their immediate outer lexical scope and not in the parent scope. The question is Java-specific.

Does this back my understanding ?

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/variables.html

The exact question

> State true or false Scope of a local variable is within a class

Comment: It would help if you directly quoted where you read that, as it does seem false, but perhaps there was some nuance?

Comment: I followed your link, but could not find the exact text you are quoting here. Could you tell us where this is stated?

Comment: Nope, the quote is in a book I am studying from. The link is where a explanation is given regarding my understanding. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

there are a few things still perhaps
"The scope of a local variable in within the function/method" yes true but try this

```
{
   int val=10;

}

System.out.println(val)
```

just create a block and initialize a variable then try to print it outside the block, it will cause an error this is the same for "conditional/looping" statements too
so, local variables aren't limited only towards function/method but the block they are defined

and if instance variables are declared within the class. how can we use it? or refer it? to invoke the appropriate function/method.....

PS: for your question, it is "true" since it is defined only inside a class maybe constructor or maybe method, and can only be accessed only up to that point

Comment: yeah true, but the given statement isolated is false as far as I know because local variables can never have class-wide scope.

Comment: yes, local variable are local to where they are defined precisely a block and apart from that we can never access them :D

Comment: But the class cannot be considered as a block as a variable local to a class is called an instance variable and is not called a local variable anymore.